Scrollview in MAUI - looks like it's not working
I am new to MAUI, I can't make the scrollview within a frame, how can I solve it?
This my code - the declaration of the content of the page:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AppMobilTrc.Pages.WithoutProgramming"
             xmlns:handlers="clr-namespace:AppMobilTrc.Handlers"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">

Here's the main frame and header:
<!-- Frame Principal -->
<Frame CornerRadius="0" Background="#E8E8E8" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0">
     <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto">
         
         <!-- Cabecera -->
         <Grid Grid.Row="0">
             <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*" VerticalOptions="Start" Background="#d31818">
                 <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="trclogoblanco.png" WidthRequest="60" HorizontalOptions="Start" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
                 <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="CONTROL DE GARITA" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="14" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="160" Margin="20,0,0,0" FontFamily="Lobster-Regular"/>
                 <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="trctrackblanco.png" WidthRequest="55" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
             </Grid>
         </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Frame>

Main content and first frame:
<!-- Contenido Principal -->
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,10,0" >
    <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" RowDefinitions="40*,50*,10*">
        
        <!-- Primer Frame -->
        <Frame Grid.Row="0" BorderColor="Transparent" Padding="0" CornerRadius="8" HasShadow="False" Margin="0" BackgroundColor="White">
            <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto, Auto" ColumnDefinitions="*">
                
                <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Row="0">
                    <Label Text="USUARIO : " VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="Black" FontFamily="Lobster-Regular" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="13" Margin="15,10,0,10"/>
                    <Label  x:Name="txtUsername" Text="{Binding Username}" TextTransform="Uppercase" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#3c434a" FontSize="13" Margin="5,10,0,10"/>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>

                <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Row="1">
                    <Label Text="FECHA :" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="Black" FontFamily="Lobster-Regular" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="13" Margin="15,10,0,10"/>
                    <Label x:Name="FechaLabel" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#3c434a" FontSize="14" Margin="5,10,0,10"/>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>

                <Grid Grid.Row="2" >
                    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*" Margin="0">
                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="P. CONTROL :" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" FontFamily="Lobster-Regular" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="13" Margin="15,10,0,10"/>
                        <Frame Grid.Column="1" BorderColor="Transparent" Background="#E8E8E8" Padding="0" CornerRadius="8" HasShadow="False" Margin="15,0,15,0" HeightRequest="38">
                            <Grid>
                                <handlers:BorderlessPicker x:Name="PuntoControlPicker" Title="Seleccionar" FontSize="13" TextColor="Black" Margin="10,0,0,0" SelectedIndex="-1"/>
                                <Image Source="flechaa.png" WidthRequest="25" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="0,0,15,0" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Frame>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row="3">
                    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*" Margin="0,10">
                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="DNI :" TextColor="Black" FontFamily="Lobster-Regular" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="13" Margin="15,10,0,0" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                        <Frame Grid.Column="1"  Padding="0" BackgroundColor="#E8E8E8" Margin="15,0" CornerRadius="10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BorderColor="Transparent" HeightRequest="38">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="0" Margin="15,0,0,0">
                                <handlers:BordelessEntry Grid.Column="1" x:Name="dniEntry" Placeholder="Ingresar DNI" Keyboard="Numeric" Margin="0,0,0,-5" WidthRequest="200"/>
                                <Button Background="Transparent" CornerRadius="10"  FontFamily="Lobster-Regular" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="80"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Padding="0" Clicked="OnBuscarClicked">
                                    <Button.ImageSource>
                                        <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesome" Glyph="&#xf002;" Color="#398bf7" Size="20"/>
                                    </Button.ImageSource>
                                </Button>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Frame>

Second frame, where I try to implement the scrollview
<!-- Segundo Frame -->
<Frame Grid.Row="1" BorderColor="Transparent" Padding="0" CornerRadius="8" HasShadow="False" Margin="0">
    <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical">
        <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto" >
            
            <!-- Cabecera del segundo frame -->
            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto, Auto" ColumnDefinitions="*" Background="#d31818">
                    <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Start">
                        <Label Text="DATOS DE ASISTENCIA  " VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontFamily="Lobster-Regular" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="14" Margin="15,10,0,10"/>
                        <!--<Label Text="1" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="White" FontFamily="Lobster-Regular" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="14" Margin="5,10,0,10"/>-->
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                    <!--<HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,0,20,0">
                        <Label Text="SALIDA :" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="White" FontFamily="Lobster-Regular" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="14" Margin="15,10,0,10"/>
                        <Label Text="0" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="White" FontFamily="Lobster-Regular" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="14" Margin="5,10,0,10"/>
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>-->
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <!-- Contenido desplazable -->
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,10,20">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="DNI: " VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="#3c434a" FontFamily="Lobster-Regular" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="13" Margin="15,10,0,5"/>
                    <Frame  BorderColor="Transparent" BackgroundColor="#E8E8E8" Padding="0" CornerRadius="8" HasShadow="False" Margin="15,0,15,0" HeightRequest="35">
                        <Grid>
                            <Label Text="{Binding DocumentoIdentidad}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="#3c434a" FontFamily="Lobster-Regular" FontSize="13" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                    <Label Text="NOMBRE Y APELLIDOS: " VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="#3c434a" FontFamily="Lobster-Regular" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="13" Margin="15,15,0,5"/>
                    <Frame  BorderColor="Transparent" BackgroundColor="#E8E8E8" Padding="0" CornerRadius="8" HasShadow="False" Margin="15,0,15,0" HeightRequest="35">
                        <Grid>
                            <Label Text="{Binding NombreCompleto}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="#3c434a" FontFamily="Lobster-Regular" FontSize="13" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                    <Label Text="FECHA/HORA: " VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="#3c434a" FontFamily="Lobster-Regular" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="13" Margin="15,15,0,5"/>
                    <Frame  BorderColor="Transparent" BackgroundColor="#E8E8E8" Padding="0" CornerRadius="8" HasShadow="False" Margin="15,0,15,0" HeightRequest="35">
                        <Grid>
                            <Label x:Name="txtFechaAccion" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="15,10,0,5"/>

                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                    <Label Text="PUESTO: " VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="#3c434a" FontFamily="Lobster-Regular" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="13" Margin="15,15,0,5"/>
                    <Frame  BorderColor="Transparent" BackgroundColor="#E8E8E8" Padding="0" CornerRadius="8" HasShadow="False" Margin="15,0,15,0" HeightRequest="35">
                        <Grid>
                            <Label x:Name="txtPuesto"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="15,10,0,5"/>

                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                    <Label Text="OBSERVACIÓN: " VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="#3c434a" FontFamily="Lobster-Regular" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="13" Margin="15,15,0,5"/>
                    <Frame  BorderColor="Transparent" BackgroundColor="#E8E8E8" Padding="0" CornerRadius="8" HasShadow="False" Margin="15,0,15,0" HeightRequest="35">
                        <Grid>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Observado}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="#3c434a" FontFamily="Lobster-Regular" FontSize="13" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
</Frame>

3 frame, footer
<!-- Tercer Frame -->
<Frame Grid.Row="2" BorderColor="Transparent" Padding="0" CornerRadius="8" HasShadow="False" Margin="0" BackgroundColor="White">
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,10" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Spacing="40">
        <Button Background="#06d79c"  CornerRadius="10" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" FontSize="13" Text="INGRESO" FontFamily="Lobster-Regular" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="130" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Padding="0" Clicked="OnIngresoClicked" >
            <Button.ImageSource>
                <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesome" Glyph="&#xE551;" Size="20" />
            </Button.ImageSource>
        </Button>
        <Button Background="#398bf7" CornerRadius="10" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" FontSize="13" Text="SALIDA" FontFamily="Lobster-Regular" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="130" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Padding="0" Clicked="OnSalidaClicked" >
            <Button.ImageSource>
                <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesome" Glyph="&#xE553;" Size="20"/>
            </Button.ImageSource>
        </Button>
    </StackLayout>
</Frame>

I've been trying for around 4 hours and the truth is that I already got frustrated, I tried consulting with chatgpt and the MAUI documentation without success

a ScrollView only scrolls if the size of its contents are larger than the ScrollView itself.  Try assigning some explicit height values to your elements
